# Limit inferior proof

Tags: real-analysis

> Prove lim inf $s_n$ + lim inf $t_n \leq$ lim ($s_n+t_n)$.

Let $\epsilon >0$, lim inf $s_n=s$, and lim inf $t_n=t$. Then $\exists N_1 \wedge N_2$ such that $s-\frac{\epsilon}{2}<s_k$ for all $k>N_1$ and $t-\frac{\epsilon}{2}<t_k$ for all $k>N_2$. Then, $s+t-e<s_k+t_k$.

I'm not sure if I can make this jump:
$$s+t-e<\text{lim}(s_n+t_n)$$
$$\Rightarrow s+t \leq \text{lim}(s_n+t_n)$$

Comment: I suppose you mean "infimum" proof instead of inferior proof. :)

Comment: To be precise, it would be $s+t-\epsilon\le\lim(s_n+t_n)\quad\forall\epsilon>0\Rightarrow s+t\le\lim(s_n+t_n)$.

Comment: @NasuSama - Yes lol. I didn't catch that. Thanks.

Comment: @NasuSama I've always called it the limit inferior.  Cf. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Limit_superior_and_limit_inferior

Comment: Why don't you try proving by contradiction? Assume the converse is true, and let $\epsilon$ be half the difference between $s+t$ and $lim(s_n +t_n)$. That would lead to a contradiction.

Comment: Also I would add that we should write $\liminf s_n + \liminf t_n \leq \liminf (s_n + t_n)$ since the actual limit of the sum might not exist. This is a slightly stronger statement, but is still true (proof identical).

Comment: @NasuSama Why would you change a correct title to somehing non-sensical?

Comment: I read, "I suppose you mean "inferior" proof instead of interior proof." It was a long night lol.

Comment: @N-7 is my entire argument correct though?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, in general, the following is true:
$$\forall \epsilon > 0, \ a < b + \epsilon \implies a \leq b.$$
The best way to see it is to draw some pictures for yourself, but here's a formal proof. Suppose for contradiction that $a > b$. Let $\delta = a-b > 0$. Then we have
$$a > \frac{a+b}{2} = b + \frac{\delta}{2}$$
which contradicts our assumption that **for all** $\epsilon > 0$ (including $\epsilon = \delta/2$) $a < b + \epsilon$.